# What is the return type for multiple possible types in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, grpc, rpc

```
fun getSummary(id: String): List<Summary> {
    val request = GetSummaryRequest(id)
    val response = client.getSummary(request) as GetSummaryResponse
    return when (val result = response.result) {
        is GetSummarySuccessResponse-> result.summaryList
        is GetSummaryFailResponse-> throw TreasuryRpcException("There was an error calling getSummary")
        else -> "No message"                      
        }
    }
```

it gives me a red line for `:List<Summary>` because return can be `List<Summary>`, `Exception`,`String`, I know I probably can use `Any` as return type.
Just want to know the best practice in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown so it is not part of the return type. You should return either `emptyList()` or `null` for the else condition so the return type can still be `List<Summary>` or at least `List<Summary>?`. You only need nullability if you need to distinguish that condition from a successful result.

Comment: Other than Exception, what are other ways to get error message? If I just return `null` error message is lost

Comment: Look up Kotlin sealed classes. That’s one of the primary uses for them.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) in this case.

First of all create a sealed class as follows:

```
sealed class Resource<out R>

data class Success<out R>(val data: R) : Resource<R>()
data class Failed(val t: Throwable? = null) : Resource<Nothing>()
data class Info(val message: String = "Something went wrong") : Resource<Nothing>()
```

In your code change the return type from `List<Summary>` to `Resource<List<Summary>>`. After changing, the code will look like following:

```
fun getSummary(id: String): Resource<List<Summary>> {
    val request = GetSummaryRequest(id)
    val response = client.getSummary(request) as GetSummaryResponse
    return when (val result = response.result) {
        is GetSummarySuccessResponse-> Success(result.summaryList)
        is GetSummaryFailResponse->  Failed(TreasuryRpcException("There was an error calling getSummary"))
        else -> Info("No message")                      
    }
}
```

The code where you call `getSummary()` should look like following:

```
val summaryResource = getSummary(id)
when(summaryResource) {
    is Success -> {
        val summary = summaryResource.data
        // Do something with summary
    }
    is Failed -> {
        val t = summaryResource.t
        println(t?.message)
        // Do something with t
    }
    is Info -> {
        val msg = summaryResource.message
        println(msg)
        // Do something with msg
    }
}
```